# test clear pytest data after running test

Tags: python

I have 20 tests in my program, through pytest, they all work by running them individually, when I run them all together through test explorer, those that are tests without a database run. but the ones that have in the database test, the first one runs the others give this error.

// failed on setup with "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'tb_function' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object."

how to run the test, and clean it when it's over for another one to come in and run right?

Comment: Show the tests : you seems to be doing the same «add function» test in 2 different tests, this can show that you need to delete the function if it exists before creating if.

Answer (score 0):

What you'r looking for is pytest [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#fixtures-api). You will have to define a fixture for your DB where you define all the tables once (probably with a class or module scope) and each test will get this fixture and use it.

Look at the following example:

```
# Standard imports 
import requests
import sqlite3

# Third party imports
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def setup_database():
    """ Fixture to set up the in-memory database with test data """
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE stocks
        (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')
    sample_data = [
        ('2020-01-01', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.0),
        ('2020-01-01', 'SELL', 'GOOG', 40, 123.0),
    ]
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', sample_data)
    yield conn


def test_connection(setup_database):
    # Test to make sure that there are 2 items in the database

    cursor = setup_database
    assert len(list(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks'))) == 2
```